# Default installation folder for qt4 on ubuntu

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, pyqt4, default

I have quite a moronic question. I installed QT4 on my Ubuntu 3.10 and I want to work with it on Eclipse with python. At some point I need to insert the folder where I installed the QT4 as an external library. The problem is that I have no idea where the computer decided to install it. I installed the QT4 throw the Ubuntu software center. I have tried to look after the folder by searching the folder finder for "QT4" or "PyQt4". I got many results and I added each one of them but still having problems compiling. Can anybody tell me the default folder where the ubuntu software center installs the programs? Or should I remove the QT4 and reinstall it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried to type "which qt", "which pyqt4" in a shell? it might be installed in /opt/

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get the installation paths like this:

```
dpkg --listfiles libqt4-core
```